# How do I print array elements with comma space in mips?

Tags: mips

So I was expecting an output like:

```
Encrypted: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

I did managed to get the array output but without the space between the comma and the next number. So it looks like

```
Encrypted: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

I'm wondering where and how should I add the space between? Below are the code snippet for the printing part

```
    la $a0,str1
    li $v0,4
    syscall

    li $a1,10
    li $s0,0
    la $a3,array
    addi $t5,$a1,-1
```

Comment: You didn't provide enough code/data. But I guess you just have to output a space in addition to the comma you are already printing whenever you print said comma.

Comment: You could create a string that's a combination of a space and a comma. Like so: `spacecomma: .asciiz " ,"`